# Python/mysql: Result into two Lists

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to plot MySQL result using Python script and matplotlib

```
import MySQLdb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
                           user = "testuser",
                           passwd = "testpass",
                           db = "test")
   cursor = conn.cursor ()
   cursor.execute ("SELECT id,secondid from table limit 10")
   row = cursor.fetchall()
   print "RESULT:", row[0]
   cursor.close ()
   conn.close ()
```

And i will plot these two lists by simple passing like this

```
id,ts=zip(*row)  #cThis will solve the problem


plt.plot(id,secondid)
plt.grid()
```

But i am quite confused to create two lists since The query result is a list of tuples.
Please suggest.

Comment: Just leave this question . I have got the answer                                      id,secondid=zip(*row)

Comment: If you've solved it, please post the solution as an answer, not a comment, and accept it.

Comment: Sorry. i didn't know about this thing being a newbee. I have submitted my answer.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

```
id,secondid=zip(*row)
```